# C#: Correctly finishing connection when sending data to WebClient

Tags: c#, sockets, webclient, tcpclient, networkstream

I need to locally test some code that uses a WebClient object for communicating with an http server. For that purpose, I decided to write an incredibly simplistic mock server that reads some bytes from a binary file and sends them to the client. Here is the relevant server's code:

```
public void Listen()
{
    TcpClient client;
    NetworkStream netStream;
    listener.Start();

    try
    {
        client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        netStream = client.GetStream();
        ReadData(netStream);
        Console.WriteLine("Writing data, sequence 1");
        WriteData(netStream, 1);
        netStream.Close();
        client.Close();

        client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        netStream = client.GetStream();
        ReadData(netStream);
        Console.WriteLine("Writing data, sequence 2");
        WriteData(netStream, 2);
        netStream.Close();
        client.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
}

private void WriteData(NetworkStream netStream, int sequence)
{
    byte[] bytes = PrepareResponse(sequence);    //get data from a file
    netStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

With WebClient I use UploadString:

```
string response = client.UploadString(address + link, data);
```

So, the thing is, the WebClient apparently receives all the sent data, but throws a System.IO.Exception ("Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.") when I close the stream server-side. If I don't close the stream, WebClient blocks and waits for the transfer to finish, despite all the data being received. I tried to substitute WebClient with WebRequest, and it also either throws an exception if the socket was closed server-side or blocks on stream.Read after reading all the data. What I find strange is that the first block of data I send to WebClient is an http 302 "Moved" response, which causes the WebClient to immediately send a GET request. Despite the fact that I send data identically two times, WebClient throws an exception only on the second response.

So - I need a way to correctly send the data and close the connection so it works with WebClient, and I would also like to know why does WebClient correctly handle the 302 response and throw an exception on the second response.

Thank you.

Comment: Some dumps of the actual data you're sending would be nice. Try Fiddler.

Comment: You're right, the problem was with the data being sent. I posted the description of the problem in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was actually quite trivial - the second http response had "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" set in its headers, and I didn't actually send the terminating zero-length chunk at the end of the response, thus WebClient was waiting for more data.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to clarify it by using the 'using' instruction : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/yh598w02

Basically, class like NetworkReader, MemeryStream, etc.. implement the IDisposable interface. If you wrap them with using, it will dispose the object automatically for you.

**EDIT :** 
Also, referring to http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream_methods%28v=vs.80%29 there some method for reading and writing the stream, you should use this instead of yours.